# What constitutes by their means for tzedakah

Tags: halacha, money, tzedakah-charity, maaser-tithes, yoreh-deah

The [Halacha](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Yoreh_De%27ah.248.1) is that Jews should give as much charity that reflects their means. My question is, how is “by their means” defined? Is it a specific percentage of their income, how much value their money has in their area, etc.?

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Yoreh_De'ah.249.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gemara ([Baba Batra 9a](https://www.sefaria.org/Bava_Batra.9a.12?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)) teaches that the minimum one needs to give to tzedaka is a third of a shekel a year. The SA ([YD 249:2](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De%27ah.249.2?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)) rules accordingly and adds that one who does not give this bare minimum does not fulfill the mitzvah of tzedaka.

**If one has the means, the SA ([YD 249:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De%27ah.249.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)) writes one should give maaser at 20% ("most laudable") or 10% ("average"), based on Yaakov's promise ([Bereshit 28:22](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.28.22?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)).** The SA explains that when a person receives capital for the first time, he should set aside *maaser* from the capital and then every year thereafter, set aside *maaser* from the revenue generated.

Today most halachic decisors write *maaser* is a *minhag* but a strong one which should be kept. For instance, R Moshe Feinstein (YD I:143) discusses how one should calculate *ma’aser kesafim* and whether it needs to be taken before or after taxes, but what is clear that Rav Moshe held that *ma’aser kesafim* should be given.